# In R, how can I check to see what values of two different vectors of different lengths are the same?

Tags: r

So, I have two different data frames and they both have different amount of columns. I was just wondering if there is an easy way to check what column names are equal for both data frames when the length of the column names for each data frame is different? I am sure I can do this using **for** and **if** loops but I just want to know if there are any commands built in R that can make this easier for me?

Thanks

Comment: You can use `%in%` or `match()`. Also check `?sets` for other functions of interest.

Comment: `intersect(names(A), names(B))`

Answer (score 1):

Given

```
a <- (1:10)
b <- (11:20)
c <- (21:30)

df1 <- data.frame(a,b)
df2 <- data.frame(a,c)
```

You can use intersect

```
> intersect(names(df1), names(df2))
```

or you can check, which columns of df1 have a match in df2

```
> df1 %in% df2
```